# how can i connect multiple devices with bluetooth technology using c#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I try to connect more than two devices to one device using Bluetooth, what's the best way if I program in **c#** ?

```
public BluetoothDeviceInfo[] DiscoverDevices();
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Your signature just says: I need a method. We´re not here to do your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of available devices and then loop through the `List` of all devices using the `BluetoothClient` class:

```
int maxDevices = 10;
List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] array = bc.DiscoverDevices(maxDevices);
int count = array.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Device device = new Device(array[i]);
    devices.Add(device);

    // the variable device will now hold a detected BT device.
    // Now you can connect to the device:
    bc.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint((BluetoothAddress)adres,service));

    // Send a message to the device
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream = bc.GetStream();
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
    streamWriter.WriteLine("! 0 200 200 210 1");
}
// the variable devices will now hold an array of all detected BT devices.
```

**Note:** `DiscoverDevices` takes about 20-30 seconds to complete.

Comment: and than i can sends information by looping the array?

Comment: @B.k What do you mean?

Comment: sorry for not being clear 
i want to send a messege to all devices , so i need to loop on the list "devices"?

and how can i send info to the devices?